# What is Constructor is assigned to object when it is not having return type?

Tags: java, constructor

I have class of student like this. Since the constructor will not return anything, then still why do u assign the constructor to object. It is exactly like the method with return type?

And What makes the difference between that two?

```
class Student { 
   int id;
   public Student (int id) {
     this.id= id; 
   } 
   public int returnID() {
     return id; 
   }
}

public class App {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    Student std1 = new  Student(1); // this
    int idValue = std1.returnId();  // versus that
 } 
}
```

Comment: Please take a lot more care formatting your code. Even in the Markdown it's all over the place. Unreadable code make the question much less useful to future visitors, and much less likely to receive answers.

Comment: And please note: you want to format source code with 4 spaces - and then you can't "bold" things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *point* of a constructor is to **intialize** a new object.

The "creation" of the *new* object (and providing a *reference* to that object) is what `new` is doing.

When you use `new` a **new** Java object is created; and then constructors are invoked to initialize that thing.

Thus:

```
Student someStudent = new Student(1);
```

creates that **new** object, whereas

```
int value = someStudent.returnId();
```

simply calls a *real* method on that object ... which happens to return an int value.

In other words: in that sense constructors are not "real" methods - therefore there is no final return inside that would return the created object. And just for the record: *not* returning an object is a very important part of constructors.

Comment: Maybe you should remove the `()` used in `new()` as `new`, per se, is not a method. It's a reserved word and this may lead to confussion

Comment: Good point, thanks and updated.

Comment: Thats ok, then what does someWhat object is conatined when the constructor is called ?

Comment: In contains the **reference** that **new** is "returning".

Comment: Ok Thanks,What will new going to return ??

Comment: It returns a *reference* to the *newly* created object.

Answer (score 0):

A constructor initializes an object, which in turn can have different properties and methods underneath.

The constructor doesnt have a return statement since it always initializes the object

Comment: When constructor dont returns anything then why it is assigned to object just like we assign the value returned from the method ?